# Keyboard shortcuts to control the sound volume on a YouTube video

Tags: youtube

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to control the sound volume on a YouTube video (UP, DOWN, MUTE/UNMUTE)?

Answer (score 1):

I found out by trial and error:
• Arrow UP: increases the sound volume
• Arrow DOWN: decreases the sound volume
• The M key mutes or unmutes the sound

Unfortunately, for these shortcuts to work, the video itself needs to be focused. But focusing on the playing video by clicking on it, stops the playback! So this is counterproductive!

Comment: Click on the page, not the actual video.

Comment: @Tetsujin Your advice is wrong: The arrow keys control the volume only if the video has the focus - NOT THE PAGE!

Comment: No need to shout. Works just fine here so long as the browser page is front-most.

Comment: Hit the tab key first. That gets the video in focus. Then hit ↑ or ↓. Working on mac as on 2022/12/07.